# Querying multiple index in django-sphinx

Tags: django, full-text-search, django-sphinx

The django-sphinx documentation shows that django-sphinx layer also supports some basic querying over multiple indexes.

http://github.com/dcramer/django-sphinx/blob/master/README.rst

```
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxSearch

SphinxSearch('index1 index2 index3').query('hello')
```

It seems SphinxSearch does not contain the function query(). I also tried to include content_type in sphinx.conf sql_query configuration as mentioned in the django-sphinx documentation. Nothing has worked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'SphinxSearch' object has no attribute 'query'
```

Can anybody throw light on how I could get ranked results from multiple indexes in sphinx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

instead of using `SphinxSearch`, you want to use `SphinxQuerySet`

for example, if i wanted to query three indexes, weigh the results using the `title`, `tags`, and `content` fields, and set custom matching (`SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2`) and ranking (`SPH_RANK_NONE`) modes:

```
from djangosphinx.models import SphinxQuerySet

search = SphinxQuerySet(
    index = "index_1 index_2 index_n",
    weights = {
        'title': 100,
        'tags': 80,
        'content': 20
    },
    mode = 'SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2',
    rankmode = 'SPH_RANK_NONE')

results = search.query('what is the answer to life, the universe, and everything?')

for result in results:
    print result
```